# Thread-safe writing to the same file

Tags: java, multithreading

I created this method to write text to the same file by multiple threads:

```
public static void ThreadsafeWriter(String text, String file) throws IOException {
    String nodeValue = text;
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    synchronized (writer) {
        String[] words = nodeValue.split(" ");
        for (String word: words) {
            writer.write(word);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

I wanted to ask if it have any errors or no, and will it cause exceptions?

Thanks!

Comment: off-topic: There is no need to define `nodeValue`as you can use `text`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `synchronized` block won't do anything; this is not thread safe.

Synchronization is on a per-instance basis: `synchronized (writer)` means that no other monitor can enter a synchronized block on that same exact `writer` instance. But you just created that writer within your method, and you never publish it to another thread; no other thread will ever see that object, let alone try to enter a synchronized block on it.

You need to create something like a static map from file path to objects to lock on (and be careful about aliases and such, which may have different paths but refer to the same file). And of course, none of that will prevent another process from writing to the file.

Atomicity with files is tricky. A common technique is to write to a temporary, random file, and then move that file to the destination path.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by synchronizing using not the `writer` variable, but another `static` variable. This way, all objects calling this method will be synchronizing using the same object, not a the new BufferedWriter each call is creating.

Example:

```
public class SyncExample{

 private static Object lock = new Object(); // the object for locks does not have to be anything special.

   public static void ThreadsafeWriter(String text, String file) throws IOException {
String nodeValue = text;
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    synchronized (lock ) {
        String[] words = nodeValue.split(" ");
        for (String word: words) {
            writer.write(word);
            writer.newLine();
        }
       writer.close();
    }
}


}
```

EDIT: I just re-read your question, sorry. Take into consideration my "fix" does ignore if the file you are trying to write to is the same or different between calls. It just makes it "impossible" to write to two any files at "same time".

Comment: _It just makes it "impossible" to write to two any files at "same time"._ ... only if all files are written using this method ... and only on the running VM ... and as long as the `lock`(as it isn't declared `final`) doesn't get a new value assigned. You should be rather careful with such generalizing statements. Look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52229426/2838289) of @yshavit.

Comment: You are right. I just assumed he was beginning with multithreading and locks, and including more details would make it harder for him to understand. I'll be more careful next time and explain the caveats